# how do i place a scroll bar outside of the div which is overflowed?

Tags: scrollbar, overflow, css

i have a page which has a centered (vertical as horizontal) content div. When the div is overflowed than a scroll bar appears on the right side of the div.

i think this looks ugly and i would like to have the scrollbar on right side of the screen as normal.

Is there anyway to fix this?

the page is available [here](http://www.pand89.nl/test/test.html)

thanks guys!

Comment: @draevor: that would cause the content div to grow and thus display outside of the area i want it to be restricted to. basically what i want is to move to scrollbar to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the fixed height and the overflow from .content.